How to calculate a provisional HTF indicator value on the current timeframe?
I hope I find great guidance with you :)

I'm struggling with an issue related to calculating higher timeframe (HTF) indicators on a lower timeframe (LTF) chart in Pine Script. Specifically, I want to calculate the provisional value of an HTF indicator as if the HTF candle were to close at the current LTF candle's closure.
Example to clarify:

Chart timeframe: 15 minutes (15')

Higher timeframe: 1 hour (1H)

Indicator: SMA 10 (1H)



At 4:00 PM, the confirmed SMA 10 value for the 1H timeframe is 70.0 (calculated on the 3:00-4:00 candle of the 1H chart).

At 4:15 PM, the 1H candle (4:00-5:00) is still forming. I want to calculate the provisional SMA 10 value at this moment (as if the 1H candle were to close now).

For instance, at 4:15 PM, the provisional SMA might be 72.0, considering the data available up to 4:15 PM.



What I tried:

Using request.security with lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off:

This only retrieves the confirmed value of the HTF indicator from the last closed HTF candle.

For the example at 4:15 PM, it still returns 70.0, which is the value from the 3:00-4:00 1H candle. It doesn't calculate the provisional value for the forming 1H candle.



Using request.security with lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on:

This works for live trading, as it updates the 1H SMA in real time.

However, in backtests, this approach is unrealistic because it "peeks into the future," returning the confirmed value of the HTF indicator at the end of the current 1H candle (e.g., the value at 5:00 PM when backtesting the 4:15 PM candle).




The Problem:
How can I calculate the provisional 1H SMA value at 4:15 PM in a way that:

Is accurate for both backtests and live trading,

Does not introduce discrepancies between backtests and live results,

Calculates the HTF indicator value dynamically on the chart timeframe?


Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
I tried this:
[m20w, uw, lw]=request.security(symbol = syminfo.tickerid, timeframe = ut_code, expression = ta.bb(hlc3,20,2), lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
I tried this :
[m20w, uw, lw]=request.security(symbol = syminfo.tickerid, timeframe = ut_code, expression = ta.bb(hlc3,20,2), lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
And I tried this:
[m20w, uw, lw]=request.security(symbol = syminfo.tickerid, timeframe = ut_code, expression = ta.bb(hlc3,20,2), lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off, gaps=barmerge.gaps_off)
But none trigger what I am looking for (cf description)

Try f_security() from this library
